# How to get admin Detail in magento2

Tags: magento2

In magento 1 We are using admin session like this

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
$userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
$userFirstname = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
$userLastname = $user->getUser()->getLastname();
```

In magento 2 how can i get this detail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get admin detail like this:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

write this code where you want admin detail

```
$auth = $this->_authSession;

    $auth->getUser()->getEmail();
    $auth->getUser()->getFirstname();
    $auth->getUser()->getLastname();
    $auth->getUser()->getUserId();
```